# Ignore function if value is the last on list

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I got a function that update my google sheet based on the last row, first cell value. So I call an api that give me some data and I verify if the last row specific value is on my datasheet. So then if I retrieve the list from sheet and see if the value is on my list (data from api). Then I retrieve the elements that above that value.

Example:

```
875
4555 //(last item on my sheet)
```

Data:

```
875
4555 !!
4789
7854
```

So it will append a row for the new values (4789, 7854).

It works when i have 2 new items, but if i found only one new item on my list i get an error.

```
while operaciones == [] or in_list(operaciones, last_ref()) is False:
    obteneroperaciones()
    time.sleep(10)

operaciones.reverse()
operaciones = operaciones[in_list(operaciones, last_ref()) + 1:None]

for trade in operaciones:
    ws.append_row(trade)
```

It works when i have 2 or more new values, but if its only one i get an error.

Comment: What is the error you get? Is it an IndexError?

Comment: Yes, but now i retried running the script and it works nice. I didnt save the error so i will continue finding the error and edit question.

Comment: I think the problem is that the line operaciones = operaciones[in_list(operaciones, last_ref()) + 1:None] may get an index greater than the length of operaciones. To fix that, you can use a negative index ... something like operaciones[-len(operaciones)+in_list(operaciones, last_ref()):]